# Policy for Assigning groupIds to 3rd party artifacts understanding

Tags: maven

I'm new to Maven and ready the guide to upload artifact to the Central Repository. [Here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html) I read the following paragraph which is confusing me.

> This information is for handling 3rd party projects which don't want
>   to upload their artifacts directly into The Central Repository. If you
>   want to deploy your own project to The Central Repository, please use
>   OSSRH Guide.

Here I got confused what does mean of 3rd party projects(I was expecting any library/jar which is not available in Central Repository)? In the above paragraph they said people don't want to upload artifact to Central Repository. then in the next line they said if you want the own project to Central please use the guide.

Then reading the next paragraph

> While most projects understand the importance of publishing artifacts
>   to Central, there are still a few projects out there that don't have
>   the same appreciation. **When a project refuses to upload artifacts to
>   Central, for whatever reason, as long as the license permits, we
>   encourage people to submit artifact bundles to Central themselves.**

Here they saying when people refuses to upload the artifacts to Central, we encourage people to submit Themeself? are there two different way to upload(auto and self)?  really confusing what they are saying here.